# Custom Visual Studio Item Templates for Blazor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, blazor, visual-studio-templates

I tried to create a new Item Template for my Blazor Projects and it hasen't shown up in the "Add New Item"-dialog.
The solution was to add TemplateGroupID, TemplateID, and AppliedTo in the TemplateData section of my .vstemplate file.

```html
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
...
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <TemplateGroupID>AspNetCore</TemplateGroupID>
    <TemplateID>MyCustomTemplateID</TemplateID>
    <AppliesTo>DotNetCoreRazor</AppliesTo>
...
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
...
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Comment: This worked for me. reading documentation, it says that TemplateID is not required, but leaving it out didn't work for me so it is in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Yep! This works. Looks like its the only specific combination of settings that gets it to show up.